# MS Word indicates a lot of misspelled words but suggests to replace by the same

Tags: microsoft-word, office365, spell-check

I'm working on a text (from someone else) and Word indicates a lot of words as being misspelled although they aren't.
When I look at the proposed suggestion, it is identical to the word indicated as misspelled. When replaced with the (identical) suggestions though, it's not marked as misspelled anymore ...

The second thing I saw was that sometimes Word only underlines part of the word as misspelled but ignores for instance the the last character.

I tried several fixes but without result: setting the language for the entire text, setting it for a paragraph, even setting it for the word itself, changed format, etc.

[image: example image]

What I just noticed now is that all "misspelled" words are words with an accent like é or è. When i replace that character myself with the same character, it's not misspelled anymore.

When I do a search on characters with an accent, Word doesn't find them, yet they are there. Already tried to change the font but doesn't change anything.

In other parts of the same document, the issue is not there ...

Comment: Thank you for the info. Did so.

Comment: Any chance some of the characters in the words are not from the Roman alphabet? For example, maybe there is an "Α" that is actually the Greek letter alpha.

Comment: No, checked that. Weird thing is that a lot of words are indicated as misspelled but not all of them.

Comment: Have you checked the spelling dictionary? I mean maybe you're writing French French, but spelling dic is set to Belgian or Canadian French. Sounds a bit stooped but...

Comment: What I just noticed now is that all "misspelled" words are words with an accent like é or è. When i replace that character myself with the same character, it's not misspelled anymore.

Comment: When I do a search on characters with an accent, Word doesn't find them, yet they are there. Already tried to change the font but doesn't change anything.

Comment: It's best to [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1771704/edit) the question to add new info rather than putting in comments. This way it'll stay up-to-date with your current situation and the relevant info is readily available. And question - does Word find the characters if you copy it directly from the text? If yes, you should be able to replace them with your own accents.

Comment: No, when I copy directly from the text, Word doesn't find them either

Comment: The language setting in Word can be by character. Select the left-off character and check the language setting for that character. Compare with the rest of the word.

Comment: All characters are correctly set to French